# Pass variable from configuration file to decorator

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typescript-decorator, class-validator

I want to create a REST API with NestJs, TypeORM and class-validator. My database entity has a description field that currently has a maximum length of 3000. With TypeORM the code is

```
@Entity()
export class Location extends BaseEntity {
  @Column({ length: 3000 })
  public description: string;
}
```

When creating a new entity I want to validate incoming requests for that maximum length using class-validator. The could would be

```
export class AddLocationDTO {
  @IsString()
  @MaxLength(3000)
  public description: string;
}
```

When updating that description field I would have to check for that maximum length in other DTOs too. I have a service class holding all my configuration fields for the API. Assuming this service class could also serve the maximum length, is there a way I could pass in a variable to the decorator?

Otherwise, when changing the length from 3000 to 2000, I have to change multiple files.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's no way to use something like the `@nestjs/config` `ConfigService` in a decorator, due to limitations in Typescript. With that said, there's also no reason why you couldn't create a constant assigned to a value from `process.env` and then use that constant in a decorator. So in your case you could have

```js
// constants.ts
// you may need to import `dotenv` and run config(), but that could depend on how the server starts up
export const fieldLength = process.env.FIELD_LENGTH

// location.entity.ts
@Entity()
export class Location extends BaseEntity {
  @Column({ length: fieldLength })
  public description: string;
}

// add-location.dto.ts
export class AddLocationDTO {
  @IsString()
  @MaxLength(fieldLength)
  public description: string;
}
```